# How to disabled table row using JS and insert the chosen option in MYSQL?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, radio-button

I have a PHP snippet that display the table row dynamically. Every row I there's a radio button with "Yes" and "No" option.

I created a JS function, when the user choose an option, there's a pop-box will be displayed.

If the user choose "Yes" option in the radio button and click "Ok" in the pop-box, the table row will be disabled even the radio button will be disable too. And the chosen option will be save in MYSQL.

How to save the chosen option in MySQL?

My JS snippet of disabling a row is not working. How to fix this?

PHP:

```
echo '<td id="resumeFile"><a href="' . $dir  . $file . '">Download Resume</a></td>';
        echo '<td id="radioOption">
                  <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="processedOptionYes" name="processedOption" value="Yes" onclick="proccessedCheck()"/>
                  <label for="No">No</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="processedOptionNo" name="processedOption" value="No" onclick="proccessedCheck()"/></td>';
```

JS:

```
function proccessedCheck(){
    var checked = null;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName('processedOption');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
            if (inputs[i].checked) {
            checked = inputs[i];
            break;
            }
        }

    if(checked == null){
        return false;
    } else if (checked == true){
            document.getElementById("resumeFile").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("radioOption").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("resumeFile").title = "This option has been disabled.";
    } else {
        return confirm('You have chosen '+ checked.value + ', is this correct?');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to disable the form elements within the table row.

Comment: what do you mean? i need is to disable the table row if the user click the yes button in that row

Comment: I'm assuming you want the radio buttons within the table row to be disabled. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, and all the data in that table row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so if you are echo'ing the whole table from PHP just preset the parameters into the table

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script>
function proccessedCheck(id,answer) {
    if (confirm('You have chosen '+ id +': '+ answer + ', is this correct?')) {
        $("#processedOptionYes"+id).attr('disabled',true);
        $("#processedOptionNo"+id).attr('disabled',true);
        var withlink = $("#resumeFile"+id).html();
        var withoutlink = $(withlink).html();
        $("#resumeFile"+id).html("").append(withoutlink);
        $("#input1".val(id);
        $("#input2".val(answer);
        $("#myform").submit();

    }     
}
</script>

<!-- EDIT: hidden form to submit -->

<form id="myform" method="POST" action="savedb.php">
  <input type="hidden" id="input1" name="id" />
<input type="hidden" id="input2" name="answer" />
</form>


<table>
  <tr>
    <?php
$dir="";
$file="";
$id = 0;
//foreach($array as $row) {
    $id++;
    echo '<td id="resumeFile'.$id.'"><a href="' . $dir  . $file . '">Download Resume</a></td>';
        echo '<td id="radioOption>
                  <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="processedOptionYes'.$id.'" name="processedOption" value="Yes" onclick="proccessedCheck('.$id.',\'Yes\')"/>
                  <label for="No">No</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="processedOptionNo'.$id.'" name="processedOption" value="No" onclick="proccessedCheck('.$id.',\'No\')"/></td>';
//}
                    ?>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Contents of savedb.php, this doesn't have to be a seperate file

```
<?php

// Check if my post array arrived, comment this line when u done
echo "<pre>";print_r($_REQUEST);echo "</pre>"; die();

// Connect to DB
// Build SQL insert string with $_REQUEST['id'] as the primary key


?>
```

Comment: i want to use a native js only

Comment: Go ahead and use native code, but the solution I posted works.

Comment: but how to insert the value of radio option in mysql?

Comment: i know how to insert values, but how to pass the values of radio option after the user click the "Ok" in pop up box in PHP?

Comment: The pop-up / confirm box doesn't return any data, you pass the data to the function via the onclick handler on the radio buttons onclick="proccessedCheck('.$id.',\'Yes\')
You can then take the id and reference an array with all the data in PH P to get the selected info via a form submit. I will update the code to do this

Comment: so the value of radio option will be save? E.g. If the user choose "Yes", the Yes option will be save right? According to the row column?

Comment: You probably have duplicate id's in your table that is why it breaks, also why I added '.$id.' after each id name, you have to increment the $id before you echo the next row so that they are unique

Comment: it's ok now :) so when the user click "Ok" in the confirmation box, the value of option will pass in the hidden form? But how the form will recognize if the row in mysql and the row in the table is the same when inserting values from radio button?

Comment: how about if the user choose "No" the row will be still enable?

Comment: Then you do an if statement, basic stuff! Please accept my answer, I can't spoon feed you anymore. Go study some code: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Answer (score 0):

For starters, try replacing:

```
        document.getElementById("resumeFile").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("radioOption").disabled = true;
```

with:

```
        document.getElementById("processedOptionYes").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("processedOptionNo").disabled = true;
```

Comment: I was trying the code in JSFiddle but could not seem to get the function to be called properly. Can you confirm that the function is being called properly on your end by sticking an alert statement at the top of the function?

Comment: it's called properly. There's an alert message when the user click Yes or No option